# Determine the sign of area formula

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

For three points in the plane $A(a)$, $B(b)$, $C(c)$ with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$, the area of triangle $ABC$ using complex numbers is equal to
$$S[ABC] = \frac{1}{4} | \Delta|, \quad \text{where} \quad \Delta = \frac{1}{i} \begin{vmatrix}
a & \bar{a} & 1 \\
b & \bar{b} & 1 \\
c & \bar{c} & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}$$
My main question is, knowing $a,b,c$, how can I find out when $\Delta<0$?

- Given $a,b,c$ find $\text{sgn}\Delta$;
- I have seen that this happens when $A,B,C$ are given in inverse trigonometric order. What does inverse trigonometric order mean rigorously and how can I find if 3 points are in inverse trigonometric order given a drawing, i.e. is there a rule?

Comment: As you may see from the equation - changing the order of rows changes the sign. I believe that if you calculate in a certain circular direction you will be able to determine the sign - CW will result in one sign while the other, CCW, will change the sign.

Comment: "*how can I find if 3 points are in inverse trigonometric order given a drawing*" $\;-\;$ The line AB divides the plane in two half-planes. $ABC$ has counterclockwise [orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_orientation) iff moving from $A$ to $B$ on the line $AB$ has $C$ in the left hand side half-plane.